# Android Development: StartApp new sdk Ad integration does not show Ad

Tags: android

I have integrated the startapp sdk for the latest google policy.
They ask me to call 2 methods for showing and loading ads.

```
startAppAd.showAd(); // show the ad
startAppAd.loadAd(); // load the next ad
```

But usage of this isn't really loading any ads.
Has anyone faced this issue?

I have the right jar added to the project.
I have given my developer id and app id at proper places as mentioned by their user guide.

If someone has faced similar problems, please help me out in this.

Comment: please tak a look on this i have posted complete way 
[StartApp ad complete way to use][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484021/startapp-ad-not-showing-on-my-app/22110574#22110574

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I figured it out and works perfectly well now.And realized that the answers for these questions keep changing because of the changing policies of google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**nmvictor** - please take a look at our answer to you on the other post you opened: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19488238/2900074

Comment: Will check that link. Btw, that wasn't by me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to call startAppAd.onResume() in your onResume() method?

If so, where did you implement the interstitial (on what stage of your activity)?